# Exporting content within div along with styled components to text/html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Here is my code for Exporting content within div along with styled components to text/html file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class App extends Component{
constructor(props) {
super(props);
}

dwnldTemplate = () => {
    var inHTML = document.getElementById('page').innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('download', 'temp.html');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + 'text/html'  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(inHTML));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click(); 
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }

render() {

const PageStyle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

const MainHeadingStyle = styled.div `
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
`;

const SubHeadingStyle = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
`;

const WrapperStyle = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

const BannerImage = styled.img`
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
`;


return(
  <div>
    <PageStyle id="page">
      <MainHeadingStyle>
        Hello
      </MainHeadingStyle>
      <SubHeadingStyle >
        World
      </SubHeadingStyle>
      <WrapperStyle>
        <BannerImage src="https://wallpaperstock.net/colorado-road_wallpapers_37483_1366x768.jpg" id="placedImage" alt="PlaceImage" />
      </WrapperStyle>
      <WrapperStyle>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </WrapperStyle>
    </PageStyle>
    <a href="#" onClick={this.dwnldTemplate}>Download Template</a>
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

After running the code, everything is fine the component gets correctly rendered with all its CSS by styled-components but when I click on Download Template link, the file which gets downloaded does not have any CSS only the content is there. It looks something like this:
[Screenshot of Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubsCl.jpg)

Here is the source code of output html file:

```html
<div class="sc-fcdeBU hnxoDZ">Hello</div>
<div class="sc-gmeYpB kcmIus">World</div>
<div class="sc-kZmsYB bifgZI">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64" id="placedImage" alt="PlaceImage" class="sc-RcBXQ gFFQMD">
</div>
<div class="sc-kZmsYB vkNaR">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

**Please provide me some solution for this.**

Comment: Is it possible that the downloaded file is missing the CSS from the React framework? Can you please attach the complete source of the downloaded html file?

Comment: @SarathChandra please refer the post again, I have added the source of downloaded html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styled component will generate a className refering a linked css sheet. you downloaded the html, but the css file haven't been downloaded with it.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. Can you please provide a brief solution for this?

Comment: I want to export the content within the div(id="page") along with the CSS(which I have included in the styled-components) to text/html file.

Comment: OK, you can write the css inline with jsx. Styled-components don't support to get the css sheet.